# (Wolframalpha) this shouldnt give x=50?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, wolfram-alpha

This is my problem:

I need x or y for the triangle area that forms between the vertical axis(y) and the function y=100+2x where the area is equal to 2500.

so I used for condition to the linear function:

knowing that the triangle area in this case should be like:
`x*y/2=area`, so:

```
x-100*y/2=2500

x-100*y=5000

y=5100/x
```

and then:

```
5100/x=100+2x

5100=100+2x*x

5000=2x^2

sqrt(2500)=x

50=x
```

the weird thing is that works for any area, and gives me the correct result for what I'm looking for, wich is x=50 and y=f(50)=200, if the area is calculated as is shown in the condition: 200-100*50/2=2500 !

```
5100/x=100+2x [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5100%2Fx%3D100%2B2x][1]
```

it outputs `x=-5 (5+sqrt(127))` and `x=5 (-5+sqrt(127))`

how can I get the same results on wolframalhpa ?

thank you ! (:

Comment: Wolfram's answer is correct based on your input.  Could you maybe show your steps?

Comment: `5100/x=100+2x`

`5100=100+2x*x`

`5000=2x^2`

`sqrt(2500)=x`

`50=x`

:)

Comment: Ah, there should be an $x$ attached to the 100 as well: $5100=100x+2x^2$.  Now use the quadratic formula.

Comment: why is it wrong ?

Comment: When you multiply both sides of an equation by something, you have to *distribute*.  Put parentheses around it and you'll see: $(5100/x)=(100+2x)$ so $5100=(100+2x)x=100x+2x^2$.

Comment: The second step is wrong.  You need to distribute the $x$ when multiplying on the RHS.

Comment: Ok, The funny thing is that I "need" that result (x=50).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made an error when multiplying $x$ on both sides.

You had $$\frac{5100}{x} = 100 + 2x$$

In order to remove the $x$ from the denominator you correctly decided to multiply by $x$ on both sides. However, when you do this you should get $$x \frac{5100}{x} = x(100 + 2x)$$
And multiplying $x$ through the equation becomes
$$ 5100 = 100x + 2x^2$$
and now I'm sure you can solve it!

**EDIT:** To address the edit in your question, 
be careful when setting up the area of this triangle because it is actually 
$$\frac{1}{2} x(y-100)$$ 
since the bottom part of our triangle is located at $y = 100$. 
[image: our triangle!]

And to solve this area to be 2500, we would plug in $$ \frac{1}{2} x(y-100) = 2500$$
And we know that $y = 100 + 2x$, so plugging that in for $y$ gives us $$ \frac{1}{2}x(100 + 2x - 100) = 2500$$
and canceling out the $100$s and multiplying through by the $x$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ gives $$ x^2 = 2500$$ or $x = 50$.

Answer (score 2):

You start with the equation $\frac{5100}{x} = 100 + 2x.$ If the left side and the right side are equal, then I can do the same to both sides and they'll still be equal. Let's multiply both sides by $x$. I get $5100 = 100x + 2x^2.$ Bringing all of the terms over to one side, we get $2x^2 + 100x - 5100 = 0.$ Next, notice that there is a common factor: $2(x^2 + 50x - 2550) = 0.$ Finally, we use the quadratic formula where $a = 1,$ $b = 50$ and $c = -2550$. We have:

$$x = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \, ,$$
$$x = \frac{-50 \pm \sqrt{50^2-4\times 1 \times (-2550)}}{2 \times 1} \, , $$
$$x = \frac{-50 \pm \sqrt{12700}}{2} \, , $$
$$x = \frac{-50 \pm 10\sqrt{127}}{2} \, , $$
$$x = -25 \pm 5\sqrt{127} \, .$$

It seems that the website was correct. Notice that $-5(5\pm \sqrt{127}) = -25 \mp 5\sqrt{127}.$ If you don't see why $\sqrt{12700} = 10\sqrt{127}$ then notice that $12700 = 2^2 \times 5^2 \times 127$, where $127$ is prime and so:

$$\sqrt{12700} = \sqrt{2^2 \times 5^2 \times 127} = \sqrt{2^2} \times \sqrt{5^2} \times \sqrt{127} = 2 \times 5 \times \sqrt{127} = 10\sqrt{127} \, . $$